# Google analytics event parameters not working

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have initialized a custom event to track my add to cart event in the google analytics. All the event parameters getting properly triggered when I try it using the google tag manager preview mode and check the events in google analytics debug mode but when I try the same flow after publishing the google tag manager changes, google analytics didn't pick up any event parameters. However it pickups the add to cart event without any event parameters. Does anyone know a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The parameters are required to be mapped with custom dimensions in order to use them in reporting. Once set, you can use that dimension as required. The mapping is done in GA4 UI. Steps to achieve the same is added below

You can see the entire mapping process in the [official docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccreate-an-event-scoped-custom-dimension). Pasting relevant information below:

> - In Google Analytics, click Admin.
> - Make sure you are in the correct    account and property.
> - Click Custom Definitions.
> - In the Custom Dimensions tab, click Create custom dimensions.
> - In the Dimension name, enter a unique name for the new dimension. You can't use hyphens in the name, but you can use underscores and
>   spaces instead.
> - In Scope, select Event.
> - In Event parameter, enter the name of the event    parameter. Click Save.

---

***Tip***: If you are using GA4 free, you need to allow a few hours to see your paramter_name in the list to be mapped.

Comment: For completeness, the BigQuery feed will be able to see your event parameters whether they are configured as custom dimensions or not, which may help, if only in testing.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue with me, just see the issue in the Link: https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/225245799?hl=en&sjid=10197652399888485580-AP

### Version

```yaml
firebase_core: ^2.14.0
firebase_analytics: ^10.4.3
firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.3
```

### Self Test

#### step1

```bash
# make sure your device has connected
adb devices
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app xxxxxx
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.
```

#### step2

open Google Analysis [DebugView](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/a224805089p310984639/admin/debugview/overview)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiQuz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQqIE.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).