# how to stop GA4 gtag.js from converting campaign_name custom event parameter name to campaign?

Tags: google-analytics-4, gtag.js

I have a website that uses gtag.js to push custom events to my Google Analytics 4 property. One of the custom events I send has a parameter named `campaign_name`. When my website pushes the custom event with this parameter, the parameter that appears on GA4 side is `campaign` instead of `campaign_name`.

My website sends the event as follows:

gtag('event', 'my_event_name', {campaign_name: 'my_campaign_name'})

I expects the event parameter to be `campaign_name` on the GA4 but on GA4 it is named as `campaign`.

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot of where it appears as `campaign`? Campaign is automatically collected dimension populated via `utm_campiagn `parameter in the URL. You need to map `campaign_name` parameter as a dimension, before you can use them in the reports. IF ou looking how to map it, please refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76605826/google-analytics-event-parameters-not-working